# Imposible configurar sendmail para SMTP en Linux, Xampp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp

He estado intentando configurar `sendmail` para envio de correos electronicos desde `Linux` en especifico `Ubuntu`, se que existen otras opciones que hacen la vida mas facil, como `postfix` sin embargo la idea es poder realizar la configuración usando especificamente `sendmail` sin embargo me ha llevado horrores y dolores de cabeza hacerlo al punto de que ya llevo un total de como 6 horas atorado en esto y no lo he logrado.

Recuerdo que anteriormente yo ya habia podido configurar esto en una maquina `Linux` al inicio me fue muy dificil, pero posteriormente ya había entendido la configuración y en otras maquinas logre hacerlo rápidamente y sin muchos problemas.

Sin embargo actualmente parece ser que han cambiado algo especificamente en `hotmail` y al parecer la configuración que realizaba anteriormente ya no sirve en lo absoluto, y la mayoria de configuraciones que he visto son basicamente las mismas pero no me han servido, he buscado y re buscado pero nada sirve.

Anteriormente use esta pregunta en el foro de `Stack Overflow` para poder realizar una configuración correcta, la cual por cierto es muy útil ya que en variadas ocasiones me funciono:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842072/how-can-i-setup-xampp-for-smtp-outgoing-email-on-a-unix-machine

Sin embargo aun habiendo aplicado los pasos tal cual no he conseguido nada.

Primeramente veamos algunas cosas:

**INFORMACIÓN GENERAL**

> - SO: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 64 bits
> - Servidor: apache (xampp)
> - Tipo de host para correo: Local
> - Servicio de correo: outlook
> - SMTP intentados: smtp-mail.outlook.com, smtp.office365.com
> - Puertos intentados: 25, 587

**COSAS A TENER EN CUENTA**

En mi caso probé a conectarme por `telnet` a los dos SMTP mencionados anteriormente tanto en el puerto `25` como en el puerto `587` y ambos funcionaron, por lo que no hay bloqueo de puertos y si hay comunicación con los servicios, cabe destacar que no intente iniciar sesión, solamente una prueba de comunicacion.

```
telnet smtp-mail.outlook.com 25  OK
telnet smtp-mail.outlook.com 587 OK
telnet smtp.office365.com 25     OK
telnet smtp.office365.com 587    OK
```

Al inicio anteriormente yo intentaba conectarme por `smtp.live.com` el cual era el `smtp` que acostumbraba a configurar para `hotmail` y `outlook` y para mi desgracia demore muchisimo en darme cuenta que el problema no era que tuviera algun puerto bloqueado, aun no se exactamente porque no me puedo conectar a `smtp.live.com` pero ya no me funciona ni por el puerto `25` ni el `587`

```
telnet smtp.live.com 25      FALLA
telnet smtp.live.com 587     FALLA
```

Realmente despues de MUCHO tiempo fue que se me ocurrio que quizas no era el puerto y no se lo que habra pasado con `smtp.live.com`, incluso pense que se trataba de que el servicio estaba caido, pero actualmente ya no me funciona conectarme a ese smtp, entonces se me ocurrió la maravillosa idea de intentar un telnet pero al smtp de gmail por esos mismos puertos:

```
telnet smpt.gmail.com 25 OK
```

Ahi fue donde me di cuenta que el problema era el servidor `SMTP` por lo que busque y encontre que ahora para outlook el `smtp` que se usa es `smtp-mail.outlook.com`.

**NOTA**: Pese a que hablamos de una cuenta de correo outlook comun y no una de office365 intente igualmente tratar de usar esa cuenta mediante sendmail por medio del smtp de office365 como medida desesperada aunque no funcionara, la verdad seria raro que funcionase, pero no se me ocurrian mas opciones.

**PRUEBAS CON SENDMAIL**

Intente usar el `sendmail` básico que uno instala por medio de:

```
sudo apt install sendmail
```

Y este mismo me arroja un error un poco diferente a cuando intente usar `sendmail` pero el que viene al instalar `ssmtp`:

```
sudo apt install ssmtp
```

Al principio el sendmail basico que se instala sin ssmtp simplemente no mostraba nada al usar:

```
sendmail -v
```

En algun punto se me ocurrio revisar el estado de sendmail, y de casualidad pude leer cual era el primer problema usando:

```
sudo service sendmail status
```

Y esto arroja:

```
● sendmail.service - LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sendmail; generated)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2023-06-28 21:37:47 -05; 17s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Cntrl PID: 53843 (sendmail)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 8785)
     Memory: 7.8M
        CPU: 83ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/sendmail.service
             ├─53731 /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta -Am -L sm-mta -bd -q10m
             ├─53811 /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp -q -Ac -L sm-msp-queue
             ├─53843 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/sendmail start
             ├─53893 /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta -Am -L sm-mta -bd -q10m
             └─53969 /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp -q -Ac -L sm-msp-queue

jun 28 21:37:47 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Tr>
jun 28 21:37:47 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx sendmail[53843]:  * Starting Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail
jun 28 21:37:47 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx su[53876]: (to smmsp) root on none
jun 28 21:37:47 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx su[53876]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user smmsp(uid=>
jun 28 21:37:48 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx su[53876]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user smmsp
jun 28 21:37:48 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx sm-mta[53893]: My unqualified host name (aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx)>
jun 28 21:37:50 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx sm-msp-queue[53969]: My unqualified host name (aelix-HP-Laptop-15-d>
```

Busque también este error y logre solucionarlo cambiando los hosts usando:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts/
```

y añadiendo al inicio del todo:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost dominio-de-mi-maquina
```

Recordemos que el dominio de la maquina se puede ver haciendo:

```
hostname
```

Esto permitio que sendmail ahora al hacer

```
sendmail -v
```

almenos me mostrara algo:

> Recipient names must be specified

Y ahora vamos al error principal y es el cual no he podido solucionar.

**PASOS PARA REPRODUCIR**

Instalamos sendmail:

```
sudo apt install sendmail
```

Modificamos `php.ini` del servidor xampp, buscamos el apartado `SMTP`:

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Vamos al apartado `SMTP` y configuramos lo siguiente:

```
SMTP=smtp-mail.outlook.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = correo@hotmail.com
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Ahora corremos el siguiente comando para crear un directorio en `/etc/mail` donde guardaremos la info de autenticacion de sendmail y de una vez entramos en el:

```
sudo mkdir -m 700 /etc/mail/authinfo && cd /etc/mail/authinfo
```

Creamos y editamos el archivo de credenciales para sendmail:

```
sudo nano .mail-auth
```

Añadimos la siguiente información al archivo:

```
AuthInfo: smtp-mail.outlook.com "U:correo@hotmail.com" "P:contraseña" "M:PLAIN"
```

**Nota:** no se si los caracteres especiales como `$` tienen problemas en este caso.

Guardamos y ahora corremos el siguiente comando en `/etc/mail/authinfo`:

```
makemap hash .mail-auth < .mail-auth
```

Ahora modificamos el archivo `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` y despues de `MAILER_DEFINITIONS` añadimos:

```
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp-mail.outlook.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5    LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/.mail-auth')dnl
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
```

Guardamos y ahora reconstruimos la configuracion y reiniciamos sendmail:

```
sudo make -C /etc/mail && sudo service sendmail restart
```

Se supone que ahora ya hemos terminado con las configuraciones de sendmail, pero al intentar ahora hacer uso de sendmail:

```
echo "This is a test email" | sendmail -v correo@hotmail.com
```

Arroja al final:

```
050 >>> MAIL From:<aelix@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=327
050 530 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [MN2PR05CA0023.namprd05.prod.outlook.com 2023-06-29T03:14:36.752Z 08DB76F0ABC78308]
050 <aelix@localhost.localdomain>... Using cached ESMTP connection to svc.ha-smtp.live.com. via relay...
050 >>> RSET
050 <aelix@localhost.localdomain>... Deferred: Connection reset by svc.ha-smtp.live.com.
250 2.0.0 35T3EPbV054506 Message accepted for delivery
correo@hotmail.com... Sent (35T3EPbV054506 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx closing connection
```

La cosa es que ya he revisado varias veces mis credenciales y si las puse bien y las he revisado y revisado y son correctas, pero no me permite aun asi enviar el correo (No llego a recibirlo), notese que he hecho rebuild varias veces del archivo de autenticacion y siempre obtengo el mismo problema.

Estuve por pensar que era un problema de alguna configuracion que tengo que activar para outlook que no ha sido especificada en actualmente, pero no encontre información relevante al respecto.

Entonces luego intente realizar lo mismo con sendmail pero ahora en vez de usar sendmail basico uso `sendmail con ssmtp`.

Para cambiar de sendmail basico a sendmail con ssmtp uso simplemente:

```
sudo apt install ssmtp
```

Entonces me aseguro de adicionalmente configurar el archivo `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` por si las moscas y aunque quizas no tenga sentido:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

El contenido:

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf                                          
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
FromLineOverride=YES
root=postmaster

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp-mail.outlook.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=hostnamedemimaquina

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
AuthUser=micorreo@hotmail.com
AuthPass=micontraseña
UseSTARTTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Una vez habiendo hecho todo esto si quiero hacer make de sendmail ya no puedo usar `makemap hash` desde `/etc/mail/authinfo` por lo que si quiero intentar volver a hacer todos los pasos anteriormente descritos cambio:

```
makemap hash .mail-auth < .mail-auth
```

por:

```
cd /etc/mail/
make
```

Si bien vuelvo a hacer todos los pasos y a lo ultimo vuelvo a intentar enviar un correo, sigue fallando, pero esta vez me muestra un error mas especifico usando este sendmail:

```
echo "This is a test email" | sendmail -v correo@hotmail.com
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
[<-] 220 BN9PR03CA0496.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 29 Jun 2023 03:29:41 +0000
[->] EHLO aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
[->] EHLO aelix-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] YWRtZG1zazEyMzRAaG90bWFpbC5jb20=
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [BN9PR03CA0496.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2023-06-29T03:29:51.838Z 08DB76CAE948AECB]
sendmail: Authorization failed (535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [BN9PR03CA0496.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2023-06-29T03:29:51.838Z 08DB76CAE948AECB])
```

Me dice ahora mas especificamente que el problema son las credenciales, pero estoy seguro al 100% (Ya que ya he revisado hasta el cansancio las credenciales y hasta he intentado iniciar sesion directamente en el outlook y efectivamente esa es la contraseña), pero no hay poder posible que haga que pueda usar sendmail con outlook.

Hasta ahora no he logrando que sendmail funcione correctamente.

Comment: La verdad es que yo te recomiendo que uses `postfix`, porque a mi me da menos dolores de cabeza. también probé `sendmail`, pero me lo desinstalé por lo complicado que era.